# Workflow with 2 databases and Blue-Green Deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services

Say I have a simple workflow like:

Develop, staging and production branch.

Staging branch has a staging environment (AWS Elastic Beanstalk).

Production branch has a production environment (AWS Elastic Beanstalk).

A database for staging environment and a database for production environment is needed (using DynamoDB).

How do you go about this? 2 separate AWS accounts (1 for staging environment and 1 for production environment)?

How can Blue-Green Deployment on AWS be utilised with this setup?

Other suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my ElasticBeanstalk solutions, I have the following setup:

1. Dev environment with Dev Database in Dev AWS Account
2. Test Environment with Test Database in Test AWS Account
3. ProdGreen Environment with Prod Database in Prod AWS Account
4. ProdBlue Environment with Prod Database in Prod AWS Account

ProdGreen and ProdBlue share the same database, and are exactly the same as each other (except each is aware of its designation in Env Variables for reporting purposes).

When I originally created the environments I named them ProdBlue and ProdGreen, but the dns names were prod and beta.

In Route53, I have two DNS records (prod and beta) with CNAMEs to the elasticbeanstalk urls:

```
myapp.mydomain.com        CNAME    myapp-prod.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com
myapp-beta.mydomain.com   CNAME    myapp-beta.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com
```

I then follow these steps:

1. Run full regression testing in the test environment
2. Deploy the app to the environment with the beta dns name (beta env for now)
3. Scale up the beta environment to production capacity and scaling schedule
4. Run sanity tests on the beta deployment, to make sure it's running as expected
5. In EB, swap the myapp-prod and myapp-beta DNS names
6. Instantly the service switches the beta environment to prod
7. Scale down the new beta environment, to zero if you like, and it's always there in case you need to rollback

For this to work, you need to make sure that:

- Your app is stateless or is sharing state using Elasticache or DynamoDB
- Sessions on the load balancer are not sticky
- You don't make breaking changes on the database structure, so both prod environments can run against the same data source

Hope this helps.